# Soap request data lost, [value: null] instead real value

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I have web service with method:

```
findOrders(Set<Filter>)
```

Filter is defined in XSD schema like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="filter">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="propertyName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="type" type="tns:filterType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="value" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Object filter looks like this:

```
class Filter implements Serializable {

private String propertyName;
private FilterType type;
private Object value;

/*getters setters*/
}
```

I am sending request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:kul="myKul">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <kul:findOrders>
         <filters>
            <propertyName>submitter.username</propertyName>
            <type>Equals</type>
            <value>someValue</value>
         </filters>
      </kul:findOrders>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But when a read request in my application i see that attribute value contains "[value: null]" instead of "someValue". Attributes type and propertyName are OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because someValue is "xs:anyType" which is represented as Object in java.

AnyType is a type that can either represent simpleType or complexType and you don't have restriction on it. 

E.g. you can have a tree structure under it

```
<value>
    <sometag>
        <sometag2>
        blabla
        </sometag2>
    </sometag>
</value>
```

As Jaxb (I expect you use jaxws-jaxb) doesn't know the type of object you will have in value it will create a more generic way to represent it so will represent the content of the field value as DOM objects.

Actually it deserialized correctly your "someValue" but just doesn't represent it as a String but as DOM structure. If you put breakPoint in your application and try do go inside the value field you'll see everything is there. But for sure DOM representation is less convenient to use.

The question is why to use xs:anyType if you just want to put some string in it?

One thing you can do is to specifically define in the xml file that you have in this instance a string like this:

```
<value xsi:type="xs:string">someValue</value>
```

This way it is explicitly defined that you have a string in this case and Jaxb will be able to map to the correct String type

Comment: thanks for your reacton :). My XSD schema is generated, so type anyType was assigned automatucally because attribute 'value' is of type Object. I cannot change class Filter, because of its use in other part of system. So probably i will have to find workaround

Comment: Well do you really need value to be of type Object and not more specific? Because anyway at some point if you really expect value to be from any type you will need to treat those type differently or to treat them in a generic way.
Another thing that is possible to force your how is generated your XSD is to use annotation on the Filter java class:
@XmlElement
@XmlSchemaType(name="string")
private Object value;
This will force the XSD to be generated with value as xs:string.

Please don't forget to vote up and mark my answer as solving if it does answer correctly your question